# JS Не могу понять, почему root.querySelector возвращает null

Tags: javascript, node-html-parser

Не могу понять, почему root.querySelector возвращает null

```js
async function getLoginPage() {
  var response = await fetch("https://naurok.com.ua/login",
  {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'include'
  });

  var data = await response.text();

  return data;
}

async function getCsrfToken() {
  var html = await getLoginPage();
  var root = parse(html); // const { parse } = require('node-html-parser');
  var csrf = root.querySelector("//meta[@name='csrf-token']").getAttribute("content");
  console.log(csrf);
  return csrf;
}

getCsrfToken();
```

Comment: Приведите html пример эл-та, который нужно найти

Comment: Не путайте селекторы, конкретно `querySelector` использует CSS-селектор, а вы ему даете `XPath`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а можно как-то xpath? Если нет, то не подскажите, как переписать через css-селектор?

Comment: Ну вы ведь можете написать в любом поисковике "CSS Селектор" и увидите кучу статей, как и что, например, [первая ссылка гугла](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-selectors), а потом сопоставьте с тем, что у вас. Вот ваша задача какая? Найти нужный тег, где указанный атрибут имеет определенное значение, ну так и смотрите что за это отвечает: : `div – элементы с таким тегом.`, далее `[name="value"] – селекторы на атрибут`, соединяете и получаете самый простой вариант `meta[name="csrf-token"]`. А по поводу XPath - наверно есть, но тут не подскажу, я не знаток JS. Гугл говорит `Document.evaluate()`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  спасибо